# I want to manage items by updated date through scope, is it possible?

Tags: sxa-search

I have 4 items of event and need to sort by updated date. If is there any way please suggest.

Comment: Do you want to sort the items in your content tree? or You want to sort them on the front end site in SXA search results.

Comment: Yes, I want on front end site. Also I tried with sort method by given this solution of duplicate question but it won't work.